# Getting a function out of a query

Tags: mysql, node.js, variables

I'm trying to get a variable out of a query as shown below, thanks in advance

```
var deutsch_meund_note = "";

connection.query(
  'SELECT count(*) as sum FROM noten WHERE id = ? and fach = ?',
  [id, "mathe"],
  function(error, results, fields) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("no deutsch_schr for id: "+ id);
    } else {
      const deutsch_meund_viel = results[0].sum; 
      connection.query(
        'SELECT SUM(note) as sum FROM noten WHERE id = ? and fach = ?',
        [id, "deutsch_meund"],
        function(error, results, fields) {
          const deutsch_meund_insge = results[0].sum; 
          const deutsch_meund_note = deutsch_meund_insge / deutsch_meund_viel;
    //this variable:           **var deutsch_meund_note = deutsch_meund_note;**
        });
    }
  });
```

I need to get the variable out of the "connection.query" function but when I try it like the example above it just says "undefined"

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I need to get the function out of the there but the only thing it shows is "undefined"